# How can I modify a layout from a service?

Tags: android, layout, service

When MyService gets called, I want to add a ProgressBar to a LinearLayout that is currently set to an instance of MyActivity.  How can I get the view/layout from within MyService?

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done this in the past is to use broadcast a message from the service and have the Activity have a BroadcastListener listening for that message.  The payload of the message can contain the value of the progress bar.

Comment: I might have to, though it'd probably get messy.  This service is getting called from a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Don't forget that the UI can only be updated by the UI thread, so even if the service had access to the ProgressBar, it would still have to call runOnUiThread() to ensure correct thread updates the UI.